# Node JS URL issue

Tags: angularjs

I am developing WEB app with an Angular and Node js, I will start my app by hitting **localhost** in the web page am having one href link after clicking that link the url is changing to **localhost/#/active** , Here the problem occurs after that if i refresh the page means the url remains same in **localhost/#/active** but the page displaying a content with respect to **localhost**?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: Are you using $routeProvider?

Comment: No am not using $routeProvider

Comment: $route takes care of all the js like location/history stuff to set your app to the url hash. You can mess with it here - http://plnkr.co/edit/g0tCe0McJM9BriJNK7XE?p=preview but unfortunately plunkr doesn't give you url/#foo so it's tough to see what we're talking about.